# Bisimilarity and Trace Equivalence in Labelled Transition Systems

Tags: terminology

I'm a bit confused regarding the relation between trace equivalence and bisimilarity. These [lecture notes](http://wiki.di.uminho.pt/twiki/pub/Education/PeC/PeC1213/PeC1213-LTS2.pdf) I found and a few others documents I've read state that "if an LTS is deterministic then two states are bisimilar if they are trace equivalent".

When reading around the topic I found [this page](http://www.mcrl2.org/web/user_manual/articles/lts.html), which shows the following image: 
[image]

These LTS' are trace equivalent and deterministic(?), why does the rule not hold that they are then bisimilar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that the LTS on the left isn't deterministic, as the label (or action) `open_door` doesn't go to a single state and hence that action is non-deterministic.

This example shows that determinism is indeed required for trace equivalence and bisimilarity to be equivalent.

Comment: Wow, I stupidly mixed up determinism of a graph as being a cyclic or not. Thanks.